# React: Caching static files in Nginx reduces speed score

Tags: reactjs, nginx, pagespeed-insights

I'm working on increasing my website speed using Google Page Speed Insights.

The website is a React app using nginx as reverse proxy.

After adding cache headers to the static files I noticed the speed reported by google dropped significantly, even though the actual requests are much faster when I check the request.
The speed score dropped from 86 to 79 (desktop) and 30 to 10 (mobile).

This seems really strange to me. Is it possible that caching is actually hurting my website's performance? By the way, if I remove the cache headers the speed score goes back to the previous levels.

This is my nginx config:

````
server {

        root path_to_site/build;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name mywebsite.com;

        location /api/ {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        }

        # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
          expires 1M;
          access_log off;
          add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        # Javascript and CSS files
        location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
            expires 1y;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }
        
        location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
          add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";                                                      }

    # more stuff here

}
```
````

Comment: Sorry we would need loads more info to help, however I do have a guess. You set the http version to 1.1, if the site was running http2 then the number of simultaneous requests would drop. Can you set-up two versions on the site at a publicly addressable URL - one with and one without the nginx config so we can test against them (as I have no doubt it will be something simple). Alternatively can you post the two reports (use Lighthouse in Developer tools -> top right 3 dots directly above report -> save as HTML and then host it somewhere) so we can see what differences there are.

Comment: Also what is in the `# more stuff here` as you haven't closed the `location / {` declaration.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie The `#more stuff here` is the part generated by Certbox automatically. I did close `location / {` even though I forgot to show it in my code sample. I also tried removing the http version and the results were the same. I did save the two reports and saved both of them in these links: [WITH cache](https://codepen.io/Theeeus/pen/MWjRVmm), [WITHOUT cache](https://codepen.io/Theeeus/pen/yLarKXM). It's a huge difference in loading time isn't it? The only difference between them two of them is the two blocks handling media and JS/CSS

Comment: It is interesting, the thing that jumps out is the "preload key requests" jumping from 4.44s to 15s. This indicates that either your server is slow to respond to requests once you put the cache in place, or that the load order has changed and that is causing some processing to occur sooner in the cached version, delaying other things (if that makes sense). Do you know how to run and read a performance trace using developer tools, that is your next step to diagnosing. Before you do that though just quickly check the waterfall on the network tab, check Time To First Byte and see if that changes.